# Fragment: setUserVisibleHint works only when moving between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

This method for fragments only seems to be called when you navigate between different fragments. It does not work when you move from fragment to another activity and then back to the fragment. Does anyone know how I can get it to work when moving from a Activity back to the fragment?:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```

Comment: You should probably use lifecycle callbacks like `onStart` or `onResume` paired with the information you get from this method

Comment: You can play with lifecycle of Fragment through Activity

Comment: I would like to and I have tried but for my requirements, I would like something to be updated when the user navigate to the fragment itself and not when the fragment onResumes.

Comment: I found onResume() to be useful when coming back from another activity